# Java mail: "network is unreachable"

Tags: java, email

Trying to send mail using `Transport.send()` (Win7, 64bit) gives a network error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:80)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:369)
```

There are various other questions about this on this site, and it is suggested to set `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to true. It seems to work for everybody, except for me!
If I ping the server, it responds normally.

I also tried to isolate the problem in a small test program, which perfectly sent the mail, but in the 'real' app, it doesn't work. I also used setDebug( true ) on the mail Session, but the debug output is the same for the test program and the 'real' app - that is up to the point where it fails in the 'real' app.

I verified the `java.net` settings, by inserting these lines just before sending the mail in the 'real' app:

```
System.out.println( "Using IP4 stack: " + System.getProperty( "java.net.preferIPv4Stack" ) );
System.out.println( "Using IP6 addresses : " + System.getProperty( "java.net.preferIPv6Addresses" ) );
```

yielding `true` and `false` respectively.  So the problem is not one of these settings. Whether or not setting `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` doesn't make any difference.

@Gimby: yes. And, if I send a mail to the same SMTP server with a regular mail client, it works perfectly.
@SME_Dev: SMTPTransport, both in the app and in the test program.

I wonder, what other network settings may be relevant here? Any hint on what might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you connect to the mail server through telnet on exactly the same computer where the sending is failing?

Comment: What is the implementation of Transport?